# json parsing in php returning Trying to get property of non-object error

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to parse a JSON string. Before parsing I put my data in JSON format, but I am getting a "trying to get property of non-object" error.

Here is my code:

```
$querys = "SELECT * FROM image_refrences WHERE building_id=''";
$rows = array();
$responce= array();
$data = $conn->query($querys);

while($row = $data->fetch_assoc()){
    $json['images'][] = array('id' => $row['id'],
                              'url' => $row['image_file'],
                              'location' => $row['location'] );     
}

$responce= json_encode($json, TRUE);
$rows=json_decode($responce,TRUE);

foreach ( $rows->images as $output ) {
    echo $output->id;
}
```

My JSON string will look like this:

```
{"images":[
    {"id":"1","url":"def6a9.jpg","location":""},
    {"id":"2","url":"def6a9.jpg","location":""},
    {"id":"3","url":"fullsize_distr.jpg","location":""}
]}
```

Can someone help me find what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `json['images']` is not valid PHP syntax, variables need to start with `$`.

Comment: The second argument to `json_encode()` is supposed to be an integer containing flags. Why are you using `TRUE`?

Comment: Why are you encoding your array as json just to decode it again in the next row?

Comment: @Barmar issue is same for $json['images'] as well

Comment: I know it is. That looks like just a copying error, which you should fix.

Comment: Is this a rewrite (for our benefit here on SO) of your code or is this a copy/paste from the actual code?

Comment: this is my own code @MagnusEriksson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the second argument from this: `$rows=json_decode($responce,TRUE);`

With that `true`, you are decoding to a multidimensional array rather than an array of objects, and you are trying to access it using object syntax with `$rows->images` and `$output->id`.

---

*Or instead*, if you want to keep decoding it as an array, then keep the `true` argument and use array syntax to access the result:

```
foreach ( $rows['images'] as $output ) {
    echo $output['id'];
}
```

---

After making the changes, your code should be like this:

```
while($row = $data->fetch_assoc()){
    $json['images'][] = array('id' => $row['id'], 'url' => $row['image_file'], 'location' => $row['location'] );
}

$responce = json_encode($json);           // Remove TRUE
$rows = json_decode($responce);           // Remove TRUE

foreach ( $rows->images as $output ) {
    echo $output->id;
}
```

---

I may be making too many assumptions. I assume you are just experimenting with the `json` functions, because you are encoding to JSON and then immediately decoding. If you actually don't need JSON, you can skip all of that and just output the ids in your `while` loop.

```
while ($row = $data->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $row['id'];
}
```

Comment: I've removed that and changed next line with this one $rows=json_decode($json,TRUE); but it is still not working :(

Comment: Have you removed the `TRUE` from both the `json_encode` and the `json_decode`? Neither should have it for the rest of your code to work properly.

Comment: @TashenJazbi - Are you defining your `$json`-variable before you start using it?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I'm assuming `$json` is defined in the preceding `while` loop, and that the missing dollar sign there is just a typo in the question.

Comment: @Don'tPanic issue is still same with dollar sign too... now updated code says " json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given" and in foreach loop it says "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Comment: @TashenJazbi The argument to `json_decode()` should be `$responce`, not `$json`.

Comment: now it says "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array" at foreach loop.

Comment: @Don'tPanic When we use json_decode();, we get an object of type stdClass as return type. so we should parse it at foreach loop like object not like array ... please change your code to foreach ( $rows->images as $output ) {
    echo $output->id;
} ... it is fixed ... Thank you :)

Comment: @TashenJazbi The code that I included in the answer with `foreach ( $rows['images']...` was to show how to access the result of `json_decode($responce,TRUE);` _without_ removing the `TRUE` argument. When you use that argument, you will _not_ get stdClass objects. I edited the answer slightly to try to be more clear about what I meant.

Comment: Thank you so much.. it helped :)